# embed swf in jquery ui modal dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm embed a swf into jquery ui modal dialog, when i open the dialog swf played, and when i close dialog, and reopen dialog without refresh the page, the swf did not loaded from the first. 
I want swf reopened from the first when i close and open the dialog

this is the code of dialoge:

```
$( "#quiz" ).dialog({
    open: function(event, ui) { $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide(); },
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: false,
    draggable: false,
    modal: true,
    width: 750,
    height:350
});

$( "#quiz-link" ).click(function( event ) {
    $( "#quiz" ).dialog( "open" );
       event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$("#quiz").dialog({

```
open: function(event, ui) { $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide(); },
autoOpen: false,
resizable: false,
draggable: false,
modal: true,
width: 750,
height:350,

close: function(){
    $("#quiz").html(document.getElementById('quiz').innerHTML) ;

    }
```

});

```
    // Link to open the dialog
    $( "#quiz-link" ).click(function( event ) {
        $( "#quiz" ).dialog( "open" );
        event.preventDefault();

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try rebuilding the HTML of the dialog each time you open/close it. I think you're just showing & hiding it currently, so it never resets.

Try out something like this instead:

```
$( "#quiz-link" ).click(function( event ) {

     // create a clone of your dialog
     var quiz_clone = $( "#quiz" ).clone().appendTo(body);

     quiz_clone.dialog({
        open: function(event, ui) { $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide(); },
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
        draggable: false,
        modal: true,
        width: 750,
        height:350
    });

    // destroy the clone when it's closed
    quiz_clone.on('close', function() {
        quiz_clone.dialog( "destroy" ).remove();
    });

    // show the clone
    quiz_clone.dialog( "open" );
    event.preventDefault();
});
```